# How to make a Lightning Component Header, always freezed(Sticked)

Tags: lightning, javascript, aura, css, component

I need to make the Header of this Lightning Component Static. As the user scrols down, the header stays on the screen to consult the field.

```
 <div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:450px;">
            <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:100%;">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                                                                    
                            <th class="textSize" scope="col" style="text-align: center;">
                                <div class="slds-truncate " title=""></div>
                            </th>
                            <th class="textSize" scope="col" style="text-align: center;" >
                                <div class="slds-truncate " title="Header Title">HeaderTitle3</div>
                            </th>
```

I've already tried the command :''slds-cell-fixed'', but it just broke the visualization, without freezing the header.

Anybody has any tip, or any information on how I can make this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line of CSS should solve all your issues.

```css
.table--header {
  position: sticky;
}
```

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position**

This acts in a similar way to `position: fixed` but will keep the element within your component. But, it still takes up its relative space (which is handy if your table has less the `height: 450px;` worth of content.)

```html
<div class="slds-table--header-fixed_container" style="height:450px;">
  <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:100%;">
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered" >
      <thead class="table--header"> <!-- add the extra class name here -->
        <th class="textSize" scope="col" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="slds-truncate " title=""></div>
        </th>
        <th class="textSize" scope="col" style="text-align: center;" >
          <div class="slds-truncate " title="Header Title">HeaderTitle3</div>
        </th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- your table items here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```